# Difference between 可決 and 許可？

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I want to know the difference between 可決 and 許可.

I searched the dictionary and the meaning is quite the same: approval or permission.

So, what is the difference and how to use them differently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are entirely different

- `可決`: approval of a matter by vote (←→ `否決`: disapproval)
- `許可`: permission (←→ `不許可`: 'no permission')

Comment: Whoa, いいえ has a kanji.